# How to group by with Zend Db

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-db, zend-db-select

I use zend framework 2 and I want to create this select:

```
SELECT
MONTH(created_at) month, COUNT(*)
FROM
requests
GROUP BY
YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at)
```

This is my function I use:

```
public function statPerMonth() {
    $select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();
    $select->where(array("created_at > '2017-07-01'"));
    $select->columns(array(
        'month' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('MONTH(created_at)'),
        'count' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COUNT(*)')
    ));

    //$select->group(YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at));

    $row = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
    return $row;
}
```

How can I realize it?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Try: $select->group(array(new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('YEAR(created_at)'), new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('MONTH(created_at)')))

Comment: Works fine, thanks!

Comment: xangxiong should write it as answer and Mondy should accept that...